# How to change gif duration with Image Magick?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I have a gif of say 200 frames, and I want to shorten it to only the first 100. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract an interval of frames from a gif, do this:

```
convert old.gif[0-100] new.gif
```